# Prestashop: How to hide the lang particle from URL on the main language?

Tags: php, localization, translation, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

Default Prestashop's behaviour is to add a language particle (ISO code) to ALL the languages, including the main/default one. So for example:

```
domaintest.com/de > german, default
domaintest.com/it > italian
domaintest.com/en > english
```

What I'd like is this:

```
domaintest.com > german, default
domaintest.com/it > italian
domaintest.com/en > english
```

It seems not possible out of the box. How to? :)

Comment: You'll have to rewrite whole `Dispatcher` class

Comment: Wow, straightforward! :D